# Morphism of sites induced by morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question comes from Milne's book 'Étale Cohomology'. I've been confused about the following construction for the past few days. He claims that if we have sites $(C'/X')_{(E')}$ and $(C/X)_E$, then a morphism of schemes $\pi: X' \to X$ induces a morphism of sites $(C'/X')_{(E')} \to (C/X)_E$ if:

1. for any $Y$ in $C/X$, $Y_{(X')}$ is in $C'/X'$, where I believe he uses the notation $Y_{(X')}$ for the pullback of $Y \to X$ along $\pi$,
2. and for any $E$-morphism $U \to Y$ in $C/X$, $U_{(X')} \to Y_{(X')}$ is an $E'$-morphism.

If these conditions are satisfied we have a functor $\pi^{\cdot} = (Y \mapsto Y_{X'}): C/X \to C'/X'$.

I believe my confusion stems from the fact that he originally claims we will get a morphism of sites $(C'/X')_{(E')} \to (C/X)_E$ , and then we seem to construct a morphism going the other way. I don't believe this is an error in the text though, as it is not in the errata and he goes on to give the following example:

ex. The identity map on $X$ defines a morphism of sites $(C/X)_{(E')} \to (C/X)_E$ if and only if the $E$-topology on $X$ is as fine as the $E'$-topology. For example, the identity map on $X$ defines a continuous morphism $X_{fl} \to X_{et}$.

But it seems to me that this morphism should be going in the opposite direction, as the pullback is along the identity map and hence trivial, and  thus by (2.) above the morphism should have to take $X_{et} \to X_{fl}$. Am I overlooking something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a few years late but I recently got confused about the exact same thing. As can be seen on the Stacks project (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00X0) the definition of a morphism of sites is quite counter-intuitive as it incorperates this arrow reversion already. My guess is that it was done to make a morphism of sites go in the same direction as the induced morphism on (pre)sheaves on said sites, as most of the time, that is what one is really studying anyway. If you have found another way of looking at it in the past few years, please feel free to share it

Comment: Also, an advantage of this definition is that a morphism $X' \to X$ of schemes actually defines a morphism of sites $C'/X' \to C/X$. It is true that Milne is not at all clear about this subtle part of the definition, which is quite unfortunate